# Recording in a training room with upside camera mount from the top

Tags: recording

I would like to setup a remote camera in a training room to do HD recording.

I already have a standard HD video camera and a Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle.

What I would like is a camera which I can mount from a ceiling bracket. The ceiling bracket I have seems to be designed for CCTV cameras, so will only really support cameras with a screw hole in the top. So to use a video camera, it would have to be upside down as the screw hole is on the bottom of the camera.

Can I use a standard video camera upside down and yet record the right way up, as it were?

Also, what are some options regarding remote HD recording cameras which can be controlled remotely? I have looked into HD CCTV cameras, but it seems that the color is not all that great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record video upside down, and then flip it using PC software. Eg. Avidemux, which is freeware can flip videos.

For sports or action, GoPro Hero is very good camera. I can stream to PC or Mac. It also can record upside down. And there are a lot of accessories to mount it in many places.